# Show that if the induced homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(T\#T,x_0) \to \pi_1(T\#T,f(x_0))$ is 1-1 then it is onto.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $T$ be a torus and suppose $f: T\#T \to T\#T$ is a continuous map. Show that if the induced homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(T\#T,x_0) \to \pi_1(T\#T,f(x_0))$ is 1-1 then it is onto.

I know that $ \pi_1(T\#T,x_0)=\Bbb Z^2 \star \Bbb Z^2$. Initially, I was thinking that any 1-1 homomorphism would be onto here in $\Bbb Z^2 \star \Bbb Z^2$ but it is not true and I can't see any picture. so please help me here.

Comment: I don't think it's true that $\pi_1(T\# T)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2*\mathbb{Z}^2$, it is isomorphic to $\langle a, b, c, d\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\rangle$ (use van Kampen, either with a polygonal representation or where both open sets are homeomorphic to $T\setminus D^2$ and their intersection is homeomorphic to $S^1\times (-1,1)$. I am about 90% sure this is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2*\mathbb{Z}^2$). Can you provide more context for this problem? Is it an exercise for a course?

Comment: The corresponding map of surfaces factorizes through the covering corresponding to the image as a subgroup. There it induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups. Hence it is a homotopy equivalence since surfaces are eilenberg McLane spaces. The only covering of  a surface of genus two by itself is a homeomorphism, hence the map is homeric to a homeomorphism and hence induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups.

Comment: No, it is one of our prelim exam question in my course I haven't learnt $T\#T$ but you gave me the definition so I would try again and maybe reply you back in a couple of days.